# Dynamically changing Reference for Query funciton on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I've got a [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yol2pDJcPdomk5eMoOxJ0uq7Igdyz76HuT8J9KkYYg0/edit?usp=sharing) where on the sheet *"Dados de Cadastro e Resumo"* on column K (from roll 7 to 29) I'm using the formula `=IF(J7="";"";SUM(QUERY({Caminhoneiro!G:I;Centralizado!G:I;Djoko!G:I};"Select Col2 where Col1 = '"&J7&"'";)))` to sum up the hours from the sheets *"Caminhoneiro"*,*"Djoko"* and *"Centrealizado"*.

The thing is, I want to make it so I don't have to edit the formula every time to accommodate for new sheets. My ideia was to use the names on column E (from roll 7 to 29) and make the reference for the Query based on that.

So far I've got the string done (on [M6](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yol2pDJcPdomk5eMoOxJ0uq7Igdyz76HuT8J9KkYYg0/edit#gid=1385032553&range=M6)), but haven't been successful on turning that on to a valid array reference (using **INDIRECT**, which I later learned doesn't deal with multiple intervals.

Comment: not possible in a way you imagine it. arrayformula does not support INDIRECT.

Comment: See player0's answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58314247/10445017