# Use cell value as range for function with multiple ranges

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-query-language, textjoin

The Goal:

using the value from a cell as range for the query function.

Problem:

it propably does not work due to it being multiple values

What I got:

```js
// Cell value that is dynamically generated (info!A1)
"abc!$A2:$H;def!$A2:$H"

// Function I want to call
=QUERY({abc!$A2:$H;def!$A2:$H} , "where Col1 is not null")

// What I tried
=QUERY(indirect(info!A1), "where Col1 is not null")

//The error
"Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is abc!$A2:$H;def!$A2:$H . It is not a valid cell/range reference"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this desired functionality is not possible. the generated range needs to be passed into `INDIRECT` and `INDIRECT` does not support arrays. ofc there are workarounds dependent on how big compromise you wish to invoke.

see: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/58314247/5632629**

in your scenario it would be:

```
={""; INDEX("=QUERY({"&TEXTJOIN("; ", 1, "INDIRECT("""&
 FILTER(A5:A, A5:A<>"")&"!"&B5&""")")&"}, ""where Col1 is not null"", )")}
```

[image]