# Google Sheets: INDIRECT inside an ARRAYFORMULA to point to different tabs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a problem with the following bit of google sheet work.  I have a table with the names of various tabs that contain data I want to sum up using an INDIRECT within an ARRAYFORMULA:

```
|sheet3|more data|other stuff|sheet77|sheet6|
```

Each sheet contains a couple hundred rows, and I don't know how many sheets I will need to INDIRECT to.

I'm then using the following formula to add up the data from a specific cell within each of the named sheets:

```
=arrayformula(SUM(INDIRECT("'"&a1:a99&"'!a1")))
```

However this only gives me data from the first sheet listed in the list ("sheet3" in the example) and none of the others ("more data", "other stuff", etc...).  Is there a way to use INDIRECT in this way to point to the cell in all those tabs?

Answer (score 0):

not possible. only like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDIRECT(A1&"!A1"); INDIRECT(A2&"!A1"); INDIRECT(A3&"!A1"); 
                  INDIRECT(A4&"!A1"); INDIRECT(A5&"!A1"); INDIRECT(A6&"!A1")))
```

or like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(sheet3!A1; 'more data'!A1; 'other stuff'!A1; sheet77!A1; sheet6!A1))
```

Comment: well shoot, there goes that idea, on to plan J then.

Thank you very much for the quick answer!

Comment: @Alice check the 2nd part: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58314247/5632629 - generating formula with formula

Comment: @Alice do not feel pressured to mark the answer as solved especially if it helped you. you are not obligated to do so.