# Google sheets countif with indirect tab stops working in array formula

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, countif

I'm trying to count how many times a name appears in different tabs by using indirect to reference the tab name within a countif formula and works fine.

However, as soon as I put it into an ArrayFormula, it stops counting correctly. Does anyone know a way around this (image link below)?

Thanks!

**Works**  =countif(indirect("Semana "&$A2&"!g:g"),$D2)

**Doesn't work** =ArrayFormula((countif(indirect("Semana "&$A2:A&"!g:g"),$D2:D)))

[In columns E and F you can see the different results after making it an ArrayFormula.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps3f0.png)

Answer (score 0):

`INDIRECT` is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA`

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58314247/5632629